# Is there a way to export a model to the cloud and make visible the simulation window prior to running the model?

Tags: cloud, simulation, anylogic

I have a model that adjust in the simulation window a parameter prior to running the model (see figure) but when I export model to the cloud the simulation window is not accesible because the model run immediatly.
Is there a way to export a model to the cloud and make visible the simulation window prior to running the model?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put a parameter on `Main` that should be "editable" upfront. Then, you can use the [cloud experiment screens](https://anylogic.help/cloud/experiment-screen.html#toolbar) to define how users can interact with it.

You must learn how to use the "[Run configuration](https://anylogic.help/cloud/run-configuration.html)" setup in your model.

Check how the AnyLogic example models do it and become a copycat :)

Comment: Thanks benjamin very helpful tips

Comment: @AlfonsoMeléndez if the answer was helpful, please flag it as such ("up" arrow next to the answer). Helps future users find this faster ;)